# How can I ignore accented characters when string matching in SPARQL

Tags: unicode, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso, accent-insensitive

I have no idea to how to compare different labels without taking accents into account.

The next query doesn't return the place because "Ibáñez" has accents in Spanish DBpedia, but it has different accents in my data source.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?iri

WHERE {

  ?iri rdfs:label ?label .
  ?label  bif:contains  "'Blasco Ibañez'" .

  ?iri ?location ?city .
  FILTER (?location = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ||  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink>) .
  ?city bif:contains "valencia" 

} LIMIT 100
```

Is there a way to not to take account of the accents?

Comment: [Try this query](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Firi%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A++%3Firi+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++%3Flabel++bif%3Acontains++"'Blasco+Ibanez'"+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Firi+%3Flocation+%3Fcity+.%0D%0A++FILTER+(%3Flocation+%3D+<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Flocation>+||++<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageWikiLink>)+.%0D%0A++%3Fcity+bif%3Acontains+"valencia"+}+limit+100). See also [this article](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtuosotipsandtrickscontrolunicode3/).

Comment: Your query and my query are the same. I can't find the difference between both. Anyway, the particular DBpedia data page that I want it is only in the spannish version http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: On dbpedia.org, your query retutrns nothing, my query returns 3 results. On es.dbpedia.org, [this query](http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Firi%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Firi+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++%3Flabel++bif%3Acontains++"'Blasco+Ibáñez'"+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Firi+%3Flocation+%3Fcity+.%0D%0A++FILTER+(%3Flocation+%3D+<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Flocation>+||++<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageWikiLink>)+.%0D%0A++%3Fcity+bif%3Acontains+"valencia"+%0D%0A}+limit+100) returns 4 results

Comment: All the differences between the queries are in accents in "Blasco Ibanez".

Comment: [This page](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Firi%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A++%3Firi+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++%3Flabel++bif%3Acontains++"'Blasco+Ibanez'"+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Firi+%3Flocation+%3Fcity+.%0D%0A++FILTER+(%3Flocation+%3D+<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Flocation>+||++<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageWikiLink>)+.%0D%0A++%3Fcity+bif%3Acontains+"valencia"+}+limit+100) may make it easier to compare @StanislavKralin's query to your original

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the [current configuration of the Spanish DBpedia endpoint](http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Acfg_item_value%28bif%3Avirtuoso_ini_path%28%29%2C%20%27I18N%27%2C%20%27XAnyNormalization%27%29%20%20AS%20%20%3FXAnyNormalization%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).  (You may find [the query I used to check their configuration](http://es.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Acfg_item_value%28bif%3Avirtuoso_ini_path%28%29%2C%20%27I18N%27%2C%20%27XAnyNormalization%27%29%20%20AS%20%20%3FXAnyNormalization%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) interesting.)

Their `virtuoso.ini` must be adjusted to include --

```
[I18N]
XAnyNormalization=3
```

-- as described in the [documentation of the INI file](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#ini_i18n_xanynormalization), and as further discussed in the [article about "normalization of UNICODE3 accented chars in free-text index and queries"](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtuosotipsandtrickscontrolunicode3/), as cited in comments by @StanislavKralin.

*(Note -- as of this writing, there's a typo in the doc; the section about "**`WideFileNames = 1/2/3/0`**" should say it's about "**`XAnyNormalization = 1/2/3/0`**")*